# Trouble installing Ubuntu with live USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb

and sorry for bothering you,

I have just bought an MSI PE60. I have installed Windows 10 in Legacy boot mode, so I have to install Ubuntu in Legacy mode, too.

I want to install Ubuntu with the Live USB. So far, I have tried with the 15.10 version and the 16.04 beta version, but the problem is always the same.

I have taken a look at earlier questions, and it seems to be a mixtures of two problems:

When I boot from USB, the following message appears:

> "Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path
>   gfxboot.c32 not a COM32R image"

After that, I write play, play-install or help, or whatever. Then it prints very quickly

> "ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected"

and it does continue until the Ubuntu loading screen, where it does freeze.

I have disabled the FastBoot mode. There is not Secure mode, as I am booting in Legacy mode.

I cannot use "nomodeset idle=nomwait", or disable ACPI (I think, as there is no grub, and as it loads almost directly the Ubuntu loading screen).

What should I do? :/

Thank you very much.

Comment: related [Install 32 bit from USB, not a COM32R, then no PAE, 64 bit doesn't work either](https://askubuntu.com/q/543151/184892)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem was due to a corrupted image file of the operating system.

First check the **MD5 sum** and check if it matches the one that is provided by  your ISO provider.

If they **do not match** then most likely the cause is this.

Sometimes the way you extract the contents of the image file may cause problems on the installation. Try using Rufus with its ISO writing mode turned on.

If all then fails you may want to try another installation media.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem on an old Thinkpad T410i (which I now use full time!) and it turned out that I had a corrupt ISO. If you know how, then check the checksum against the checksums documented here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

I have also found that the `Universal USB Installer`[here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) produces the most reliable Live USB discs. Both Unetbootin and Ubuntu's built-in startup medium, in my experience, commonly create strange errors such as this.

As an aside, you should really be asking this on the Ask Ubuntu site here: https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1325801). It happens when you create a bootable USB stick with an older version of Ubuntu than the version being installed on the USB stick.

You can type **live** then press **Enter** to boot. This only gets around the issue and does not fix it as you have to do it every time you boot the USB stick..

---

To fix the USB installation so you do not have to type **live** and hit **Enter** every time you want to use it to live boot:

In the boot: prompt after you hit the error above, type **live** and press **Enter**, to start the Live USB session.

Open a terminal (e.g. with Ctrl+Alt+t) and type each command line below one by one:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install syslinux
mount | grep cdrom
```

The last command above tells you to which device your bootable USB is on.

Important! replace **`<device>`** in the command below in the terminal with the device in the output of the last command above. Which will be something like `/dev/sdb1`

```
syslinux <device>
```

For a more detailed version of this answer see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/746412/623554).